# Postresql update limited rows and return old values

Tags: postgresql

I have table with logs and when they requested -> they change seen status to true. Problem is that i don't need to update rows that seen is already true, only return them. Is there a way to do it?

```
logs
id | seen
1  | false
2  | true

UPDATE logs as new
SET seen=true 
FROM (SELECT * FROM logs WHERE seen  is not null LIMIT 5) as old
WHERE new.id = old.id //if i add here "AND old.seen=false" then nothing will return
RETURNING old.seen
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The previously unseen record is returned and updated for me with your statement: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=12bc5aeae6cfa649d3d330cc52d7ee3d

Comment: @stickybit it's will not on second select (after seen updated) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=a99445bebbff4e13dc03e8cdc0524888

Comment: When repeating it isn't unseen anymore, so it's no surprise that it isn't returned the second time. Or I still don't get the problem...

Comment: @stickybit problem is that i always need this rows and if they not seen, them just make them seen .

Comment: OK, but then you just don't filter for `old.seen = false` as you already found out.

Comment: @stickybit then all rows will be updated without reason :)

Answer (score 0):

Your *sub-query* should be filtered for "unseen" records and there is no need to return all columns either:

```
(SELECT id FROM logs WHERE NOT seen LIMIT 5)
```

This will return the ids for up to 5 records in the `log` table that have `seen` equal to `false`.

The updated solution would look like this:

```
UPDATE logs
SET seen = true
FROM (SELECT id FROM logs WHERE NOT seen LIMIT 5) AS unseen
WHERE logs.id = unseen.id
RETURNING id; -- Returning `seen` would only return false. `id` is more useful, no?
```